# Create log file of copied files with path - VBScript

Tags: logging, vbscript

Below is the code I am using.
I am copying files & Subfolders from one directory to a network share, then deleting all files and subfolders from source directory.

I would like to log, files copied (with path), username, date & time.
The code below works well for the copying and deleting, I am just having a hard time figuring how to add in logging.  I am a total noob to vbscripting please bear with me.
I would also like to point to where the log will be created (local machine) and the log will need to append.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objshell.run "cmd /C robocopy J:\TestData\ J:\PushDataScript\Versa\ /move /e /log:J:\PushData.log"


'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set folder = fso.GetFolder("J:\SourcePath\")

' delete all files in root folder
'for each f in folder.Files
'On Error Resume Next
'name = f.name
'f.Delete True
'On Error GoTo 0
'Next

' delete all subfolders and files 
'For Each f In folder.SubFolders
'On Error Resume Next
'name = f.name
'f.Delete True
'On Error GoTo 0
'Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `robocopy`:

```
robocopy "J:\SourcePath" "\\DestPath\Test" /move /e /log:"C:\path\to\your.log"
```

What username and date/time do you need to be logged? User running the script and timestamp of script running? The latter is already logged by `robocopy`, the former you'd need to add yourself.

Comment: I updated my question with your line.  The log is more than enough, and will do.  This also copies the files in the "testdata" source folder, however it REMOVES the "testdata" source folder.  I need the source folder to stay and everything inside it to go.  Can you help with that now?   Otherwise everything seems to work.  See my question for the code I have down.

Comment: If you can't simply re-create the source folder you could change `/move` to `/mov` and remove the subfolders in the sourcefolder with VBScript code.

Comment: Thank you.  You are right, I could just tell it to recreate the folder.  I did try just robocopy with copy command, and that actually works fine...thinking I would use the vbscript portion to allow the deletion of the dir's and files, the problem now is it seems right after the cmd runs, the vbscript deletes the files and folders before the log is written.  You know of a quick way for the vbscript to wait until copying is done?

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it, added ,1,true to end of cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

Does the log need to be itemized with each copied object timestamped or do you just need to log that the job was run and have one entry/timestamp per run?

If you just need to log all these activities as one job then you could switch from running xcopy from the command shell to using .MoveFolder method instead.

Comment: I need it to tell me what files (with path) were copied, time & date of files copied.  I really do not need the user name.  This script will be ran as a task every 5 min on a server.  Errors will not be seen, so a log of what files have been copied and when is needed.  Hope this answers you question.  Thank you.